# Comparing Expression<Func<T, bool>> to bool in query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

How would you compare `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` to `bool` in an Entity Framework query?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Expression<Func<Errand, bool>> isClosed = (x)
    => x.ClosedDate.HasValue;

bool input = false;

var model = db.Errands
    .Where(isClosed == input) // comparing to just boolean is not valid
    .ToList();
```

How could you achieve this?

Comment: Are you able to change the expression at all?

Comment: Yes, but I want to be able to keep the expression itself generic, should I ever want to alter it. It is reused many times in my code.

Comment: @Corak It's an `Expression` not a `Func`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create the expression dynamically with a method:

```
public Expression<Func<Errand, bool>> IsClosed(bool closed)
{
    return x => x.ClosedDate.HasValue == closed;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
bool input = false;

var model = db.Errands
    .Where(IsClosed(input))
    .ToList();
```